# Install BIDS 2008 with SQL Server 2012 Environment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bids

I have installed VS2012 and SqlServer2012 in my machine.
I have installed sql server data tools 2012 in other to enable BI project in my VS environment.

Now, I'm having a project which the project requirement is using BIDS 2008.

The question is :

- Can I install only the BIDS 2008 side by side with my BIDS 2012 along in my machine?
- How can I fix this situation?

Comment: I've usually found that installing different versions side by side is okay, but generally only if you install the earlier one first - or in this case, if you're willing to uninstall the later versions, then install the target version, then reinstall everything that came out afterwards.

Comment: the problem is, sql server 2008 cant install thru a win8 machine.

Comment: No, I agree, it can't. But since you a) Didn't mention or tag your OS in your question, and b) asked if you could install both together, it was a *reasonable* expectation that you had already determined whether or not the products could be installed at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can install both side-by-side, but you will have to ensure that your SQL 2008 install is slipstreamed with **SP3** to ensure it will install on Windows 8.

Windows8 supported SQL Server versions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2012/09/01/installing-sql-server-on-windows-8.aspx

How to slipstream SQL 2008 installer: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955392